# Display a list of user defined functions in the Python IDLE session

Tags: python, function, autocomplete

Is it possible to display a list of all user functions in the IDLE session?

I can see them popping up in the autocomplete, so maybe there is other way to just display only the user functions defined for the session. It is useful when you forget the name of the function. And also when you want to make sure that you don't lose source code for a function when a session is closed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should give you a list of all functions in the global scope:

```
import types
print([f for f in globals().values() if type(f) == types.FunctionType])
```

Comment: I tried callable(f) and it did what I wanted. It may return more objects than you want though.

Comment: for example, classes are callable.

Comment: This works with version 2,7 but I keep getting a syntax error when trying with 3,5. How could this be modified to work with 3,5?

Answer (score 8):

This should work:

```
print([f for f in dir() if f[0] is not '_'])
```

Tested on version `3.5.2`.

`dir()` will essentially give you a list of *callable* objects within the current scope.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question... try [dir()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir)

```
import my_module
dir(my_module)
```

just edit what lunixbochs wrote

```
def fun(): pass
print([f.__name__ for f in globals().values() if type(f) == type(fun)])
```

Comment: I'm interested in functions in the current Python session defined by the users, that do not belong to a module.

Answer (score 1):

You can list all user-defined functions without any imports by

```
print([f.__name__ for f in globals().values() if type(f) == type(lambda *args: None)])
```

Note that
`lambda *args: None` stands for function that does nothing and can be replaced by any arbitrary function.