# python calling custom function from bash shell

Tags: python, bash, shell

How can I call the custom-defined function in a python script from a bash shell?

I tried to use sys.argv[1], but not working properly.

for example,

```
import sys

if __name__=='__main__':
    try:
        func = sys.argv[1]
    except: func = None

def function1():
~~~~~~~~
return a

def function2():
~~~~~~~~
return b
```

here, I want to call the function 1 or function 2 by typing like

$ script.py function1

$ script.py function2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting the name of function , but you are not running it. You should check first if the func name is one of your functions than execute it:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    try:
        func = sys.argv[1]
    except: 
        func = None

functions = {    
              "function1": function1,
              "function2": function2
              }

if func in functions:
    functions[func]()
```

---

A simpler solution:

```
 if func == "function1":
     function1()
 elif func == "function2":
     function2()
```

Comment: Wouldn't a `dict` of functions be even better?

Comment: It works perfectly when the command line does not requires additional input arguments. But when running function has something like
def func1():
    input_data = input("please input 1 or 2")
    if input_data == "1":
        print("1")
    if input_data == "2":
        print("2")
then it gives a SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing.
How can I handle this?

Comment: @jin890 that's another problem,  use `raw_input()` instead  of `input()` . Please conisder to upvote the answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use argparse module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse

You will thank yourself later.

For your case - since you need to call only 1 function at the time - you can use positional arguments:

```
import argparse

def function1():
    print("1")

def function2():
    print("2")

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

F_MAP = {'function1': function1,
         'function2': function2}

parser.add_argument('function', choices=F_MAP.keys())

args = parser.parse_args()

F_MAP[args.function]()
```

As a bonus you get a nice help page when calling with -h argument :)

Answer (score 1):

@bigOTHER's answer is good and correct, but if you're looking to build a relatively complex text UI, maybe have a look at something like [Click](http://click.pocoo.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer [Display a list of user defined functions in the Python IDLE session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315496/display-a-list-of-user-defined-functions-in-the-python-idle-session)

```
import types
list_function = [f for f in globals().values() if type(f) == types.FunctionType]
```

This will return list of available functions, Then you can check if any of these contain sys.argv[1], If yes then you can call your function as

```
list_function[index]()
```